# Get list of headers for a given element python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file like below.

[image: Data.csv]

I'm trying to get the list (not necessarily a Python list structure, but basically all the instances in whichever format) of headers when an ID (element from column1) is given as input, i.e., for example, if I give A1 as input, it should return me `Head1,Head2,Head4`. Similarly, for C1 it'd be `Head1,Head3` and the same way for the rest of the ID's. I can get a list of headers irrespective of the ID by using `list(data.columns.values)` but I need to do with respect to ID's now. I really appreciate any help.

EDIT- 
I need the headers and not the row values. By headers I mean, if I give A1 as input, it should return me `Head1,Head2,Head4` and not `2,.,NA`.

Comment: When I import your data I get `NaN` values rather than empty because those column dtypes are numeric, anyway this sort of gives you what you want: `df[df['Code'] == 'SFDT-09-04-0001'].dropna(axis=1).columns` but this will include the `Code`column unless you set it to an index, in which case: `df[df.index == 'SFDT-09-04-0001'].dropna(axis=1).columns` will give you what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Code` is your index then the following will do what you want:

```
In [43]:

df[df.index == 'SFDT-09-04-0001'].dropna(axis=1).columns
Out[43]:
Index(['dID', 'cID', 'sID', 'Other_Data'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Hi EdChum! Thank you for your response. I'm sorry I didn't frame my question very well. I need the headers and not the row values. By headers I mean, if I give A1 as input, it should return me `Head1,Head2,Head4` and not `2,.,NA`.

Comment: So you want the first row where there are non empty/NaN values?

Comment: Exactly! For each ID (which will be given as input), I need the headers (first row) where there are non empty values (NA can be considered a value too, as long as the cell is not completely blank)

Comment: But when you import this csv, you will not get empty values, you will get `NaN`, you'll only get empty values if they are strings

Comment: OK. So could you please tell me, for A1, my output would be `Head1,Head2`?

Comment: Sure. Give me a minute